# Nginx reverse proxy not passing x-forwarded-proto header when client is Safari, works with Chrome/Firefox

Tags: node.js, nginx, express-session

I have my production server running behind an nginx reverse proxy, below is the nginx config

```
location /ac-hoteling {
    try_files $uri /ac-hoteling/myoffice/index.html;
    location ~ \.(css|js|png|jpeg|jpg|svg)$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
    }
    location /ac-hoteling/api/ {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8000;
    }
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

This is my `express-session` config:

```
const sessionConfig = {
  secret: process.env.COOKIE_SECRET,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  proxy: true,
  cookie: {
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
    ...appCookieOptions,
  },
};
```

Below is the function which `express-session` uses to check if the request is secure

```
function issecure(req, trustProxy) {
  // socket is https server
  if (req.connection && req.connection.encrypted) {
    return true;
  }

  // do not trust proxy
  if (trustProxy === false) {
    return false;
  }

  // no explicit trust; try req.secure from express
  if (trustProxy !== true) {
    return req.secure === true
  }

  // read the proto from x-forwarded-proto header
  var header = req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] || '';
  var index = header.indexOf(',');
  var proto = index !== -1
    ? header.substr(0, index).toLowerCase().trim()
    : header.toLowerCase().trim()

  return proto === 'https';
}
```

On Chrome/Firefox I am getting the `x-forwarded-proto` header, but when I use Safari i don't get this header, and because of which this function returns false and in turn`connect.sid` cookie is not being set by the server.

So essentially my session is not persisting only when i use Safari

Comment: Are you sure the header is not set? Since nginx is in front of your node app, it **always** set the `x-forwarded-proto` header. There is no logical reason why nginx should set this for firefox/chrome but not for safari. Either it works or not.

Comment: @Marc yes exactly, but i was able to fix this just now. I moved the `proxy-set-header...` line outside of this `location` block and put it directly under the `server` block. I'm still not sure why it didn't work inside the location block. I'm can only thing that the location path doesn't match when using Safari, but that is weird.